# How to get list of Departments in Active directory using PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, active-directory, ldap

I need to fetch **only departments values** from Active Directory using ldap. 
One way is to use this filter `$filter = '(objectClass=user)';`  and set ldap_search() attributes parameter to  `array('department')`
The problem with this is that I receive all entries and some of them are duplicate. Does somebody has some suggestions? If it's helping, I'm using Symfon2 and I have ldap library

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Do you have problems using ldap or do you not know how to remove duplicates using PHP?

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicates, I need a query I can use to fetch all departments without duplicates so I won't need to lose time with removing them later.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the current code you are using?

Comment: I've already put in the post what I am using: the filter and the attribute from ldap_search(). The rest are the classic ldap_connect(), ldap_bind() and ldap_get_entries().

`$filter = '(objectClass=user)';
$attributes = array('department');
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $adSearchSuffix, $filter, $attributes);`

Answer (score 1):

Using your filter you fetch LDAP-Entries for users that have a certain attribute (department in your case) set. So your result is a list of user-nodes. There is no way to reduce this list of user-nodes to have a distinct list of the attribute-value as that would mean removing users from the list. Which ones should be removed as you explicitly searched for all the users?

So the only way to go is to use something like the following (untested) code-snippet to get your list from such a search-result:

```
$departments = [];
$entry = ldap_first_entry($connect, $result);
do {
    $attributes = ldap_get_attributes($connect, $entry);
    $departments[$attributes['department'][0]] = $attributes['department'][0];
} while ($entry = ldap_next_entry($connect, $entry));
print_R($departments);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ask AD for a deduplicated list of `department` values. The closest you could do is a filter like this: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(department=*))` and then deduplicate the list client-side. Note that this won't give you department values on contacts, groups, or computers, for example. If you need those too you'll need to update the query to include those object types you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah, but using this I will get all departments of all users. I thought that maybe there is a way to extract not information about users and from there to take whatever I want, but to just query a specific field that I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible.